# Can i use the inner classes which is declared in a controller in another class? Is that a best practice?

Tags: controller, wrapper-class

I have few inner classes that i declared in a controller. Now came the need to use the inner classes in some another classes and methods. That means i can instantiate and use the inner class instances for some logic purposes. In order to access the inner classes i am using the following syntax,

```
OpenDocumentsController.SalesOrder OSO = new OpenDocumentsController.SalesOrder();
```

SalesOrder is the inner class in the OpenDocumentsController which have the following attributes.

```
 public class SalesOrder{
        public String OrderNo{get; set;} //VBELN
        public String PurchaseOrderNo{get; set;} //BSTNK
        public String SalesOrg{get; set;} //VKORG
        public String Amount{get; set;} //NETWR        
        public String Curren{get; set;} //WAERK
        public Date DocumentDate{get; set;} //AUDAT
        public String DocumentDateCSV{get; set;} //AUDAT
        public String Product{get; set;} //QUANTITY       
    }
```

1. Should we create the inner class or wrapper class as a separate independent class to use it in different places?
2. Is that best practice to use the inner class that is defined in a controller?

Please suggest.

Thanks, Baskaran

Comment: The term subclass is normally used when describing a class that extends (inherits from) another class. I think you are talking about inner classes (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_class).

Comment: Thanks @KeithC. My apologies. Its my bad. I totally messed up here. It should be read as Inner Classes.

Answer (score 1):

1)  If you are using a class in multiple places, I would say that you should put it in it's own class.

2) If you are using an Inner class from a different class, it creates a sort of coupling between your code that isn't healthy and so should have it in another class.  Although, you will need to be careful if you plan on making changes to your Subclass if it is used in multiple places.